# iptables forward all traffic except one

Tags: iptables

I am configuring my raspberry pi running Raspbian as a WIFI access point

using `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` to forward all traffic to ethernet and give wifi clients internet access

How do I make it so that if any client makes a request to a specific ip and port `10.10.10.10:8080` for example it will be forwarded to `127.0.0.1:8080` to be processed by a local http server running on the pi

if its easier I am ok with forwarding all traffic on port 8080 to `127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score 0):

an answer that didnt work for this question https://serverfault.com/a/991336/948403 worked for me.

Adding `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.2.X --dport 80 -jDNAT --to-destination 10.23.220.88:80` in addition to the `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` works as expected